# how to call a cshell script with python

Tags: command-line, python

How can I call an external c shell script with python?
The command line looks like this in Ubuntu:

```
return_process 12345 123.zip "vv" 1
```

How can I modify it, if I am working with a stack, and the required inputs  (date_ID and .zip files) are saved as variables. Like the zipfiles are in a text file and I saved it into a variable f:

```
            f = os.path.join(path, filename)
            date_ID=(filename[17:25]))
            os.system("import_S1_TOPS_modified 20170121 f vv 1")
```

Comment: Maybe [Calling an external command in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/89228/5830574) is helpful.

Comment: Please don't add further questions to your original question. If you have new questions, post them separately. When you change the question then the already posted answers may look silly which we all want to avoid. And as this is not really related to Ubuntu but to programming in general, I suggest asking those questions over on https://stackoverflow.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple solution will be using python `os.system`

```
import os
os.system("return_process 12345 123.zip vv 1")
```

[python os docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html)

Comment: Thanks it worked. Now I want to modify it, that it can work with a stack. So automatized for more files...